# How to make a directory iOS?

Tags: objective-c, cydia

Okay,

So I have a Cydia app that I need to update. I am aware with Cydia apps that they don't have a Documents folder, so you have to make one. And here's how I made it before in iOS 4 (which doesn't work on iOS 5):

```
mkdir("/var/mobile/Library/APPNAME", 0755);
mkdir("/var/mobile/Library/APPNAME/Documents", 0755);

NSString *foofile = @"/var/mobile/Library/APPNAME/Documents/database.db";
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:foofile];

if (fileExists == TRUE) {
    NSLog(@"already exists");
} else {
    NSLog(@"doesn't exists");
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]autorelease];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *documentDBFolderPath = @"/var/mobile/Library/APPNAME/Documents/database.db";

    NSString *resourceDBFolderPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.db"];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:resourceDBFolderPath toPath:documentDBFolderPath error:&error];

}
```

I also included code that copies the database file to that folder, too. That doesn't work (even when I create the folder manually via SSH).

Please help! Thanks.

Comment: What is going wrong, or what other piece of code could I use to create directories?

Comment: Right, what is going wrong?  You haven't told us.  No error messages, no description of the failure.

Comment: @Daniel R Hicks: Nothing is happening.. After pasting from the code below, I DO get an error... `Create directory error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 513.)" UserInfo=0x1c2650 {NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Library/APPNAME, NSUnderlyingError=0x1c3520 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted"}`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Here is the method I made to create directories

```
-(void)createDirectory:(NSString *)directoryName atFilePath:(NSString *)filePath
{
    NSString *filePathAndDirectory = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:directoryName];
    NSError *error;

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:filePathAndDirectory
                                   withIntermediateDirectories:NO
                                                    attributes:nil
                                                         error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Create directory error: %@", error);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the error I get... `The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted`

Comment: This might be what your looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650488/is-an-iphone-apps-document-directory-var-mobile-documents-or-var-mobile-libra

Answer (score 5):

Try using `createDirectoryAtURL:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:`.

[`NSFileManager` Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/NSFileManager_Class.pdf#page21):

> `createDirectoryAtURL:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:`
>
> Creates a directory with given attributes at the specified path.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `url` - A file URL that specifies the directory to create. 
>   If you want to specify a relative path, you must set the 
>   current working directory before creating the corresponding 
>   NSURL object. This parameter must not be nil.
>
> `createIntermediates` - If `YES`, this method creates any non-existent
>   parent directories as part of creating the directory in url. If `NO`,
>   this method fails if any of the intermediate parent directories does
>   not exist. This method also fails if any of the intermediate path
>   elements corresponds to a file and not a directory.
>
> `attributes` - The file attributes for the new directory and any newly created
>   intermediate directories. You can set the owner and group numbers,
>   file permissions, and modification date. If you specify nil for this
>   parameter or omit a particular value, one or more default values are
>   used as described in the discussion. For a list of keys you can
>   include in this dictionary, see “Constants” (page 54) section lists
>   the global constants used as keys in the attributes dictionary. Some
>   of the keys, such as NSFileHFSCreatorCode and NSFileHFSTypeCode, do
>   not apply to directories.
>
> `error` - On input, a pointer to an error object. If an error occurs, 
>   this pointer is set to an actual error object containing the error 
>   information. You may specify nil for this parameter if you do not 
>   want the error information.
>
> Return Value
>  
>   `YES` if the
>   directory was created or already exists or NO if an error occurred.

Comment: Seems Im a bit slow when answering from my iPad..., the other answer appears to be pretty much the same as this.

Answer (score 3):

Check [NSFileManager's class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html). To create folders you need `createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:`

Comment: I tried that and no folder was created... I think that's only for OSx, not iOS?

Comment: Have you used `YES` as argument of `withIntermediateDirectories:` ?

Comment: `NSFileManager *NSFm= [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
    [NSFm createDirectoryAtPath:@"/var/mobile/Library/APPNAME" withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
    [NSFm createDirectoryAtPath:@"/var/mobile/Library/APPNAME/Documents" withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];` was the exact code i used...

Comment: Assuming `/var/mobile/Library/` exists, you shouldn't need the first call, just the second. Are you sure you have the correct write permissions? What error does it return?

Answer (score 1):

[Superb Techotopia explanation of iOS5 filesystem](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_iPhone_iOS_5_Filesystem_Directories)

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, returns true if exists or created.

```
func ensureDirectoryExists(path:String) -> Bool {

    if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(path) {
        do {
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```